# Auto Update Add-in for Excel 2013?

Tags: c#, excel, com, updates

I have a COM AddIn that I've developed myself and it needs to be updated occasionally.

Since the only way for us to make it work was to use Visual Studios Publish method, it leaves us with a ClickOnce solution. This is undesireable as we would have wanted to use EasyInstall to deploy and update the solution and EasyInstall can't use ClickOnce applications in that context.

It needs to be an MSI file.

It doesn't seem like I can do that however so my next idea is to have either of these two options:

- Whenever the AddIn loads it checks for an Update somewhere on one of our file servers and then updates if it finds that it's current version is lower than that of the update on the server.
- An "Update" button is placed in the Excel AddIn. Now and again the user can click it if the AddIn stops working and perhaps solve the issue.

Obviously Option 1 would be the one I'd want but I can't really find anything on the subject.

How would I go about making my AddIn update itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured out how to do it if you make use of the Auto Update function found in Visual Studio:

To anyone else running into this issue make sure your Publish and Installation URLs don't have the `&` sign in them.

Microsoft is aware of this parsing issue but they have also said they won't fix it.